# Is it possible to have the text changed based on time?

Tags: javascript, html, time

I would like to make a website for my mum which will say different things for Mother's Day based on the time.

For example:

```
 - From 12 AM to 8 AM it says
```

> "Hey! It's early don't wake up yet!"

```
 - From 8 AM to 12 PM it says
```

> "Morning! Relax, it's Mother's Day. Have a great day!"

You get the idea.

I am making it using HTML. But will probably need JavaScript which I have never used before and not sure how to put in the code. I don't know where to begin.

p.s. I know I'm leaving it late but they say it's better late than never.

Comment: Did you try to surf the internet (YouTube specifically)? There are dozens of tutorials for JS and how you could make your website a dynamic one, Your website logic will be something like this, (1) Get current time using JS, (2) Make `if` conditions for messages that you wanna display, (3) Change the innerHTML of an element with the message you want, Of course it could have other ways to do it but just search and you will find the answer, [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) is a tutorial for JS syntax.

Comment: 1. get the current time 2. find out what part of day it represents 3. update HTML accordingly  NOTE: You can probably Google this and find a complete script for doing exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bzcrv411/13/

You still need to refresh the website manually. If you want to do this automatically, you'll need to look into

> Javascript Events

or even

> window.requestAnimationFrame

Goodluck ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Happy Mother's day!</title>

  <style>
    body {
      background: lightgreen;
    }
    #comment {
      display: block;
      margin: 500px auto 0 auto;
      font-size: 32px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="comment"></div>

    <script>
        var date, commentElement;

(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var commentElement = document.getElementById("comment");
  var year = date.getFullYear(),
        month = date.getMonth(),
      day = date.getDate(),
      hours = date.getHours();

  if (year === 2018 && month === 5 && day === 13) {
        if (hours > 0 && hours < 12) {
        commentElement.innerHTML = "Hey! It's early don't wake up yet!";
      } else if (hours >= 12 && hours < 20) { 
        commentElement.innerHTML = "Morning! Relax, it's Mother's Day. Have a great day!";
      } else {
        commentElement.innerHTML = "";
      }
  } else {
    commentElement.innerHTML = "Nothing to see here!";
  }
})();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just an addition: a simple solution to needing to refresh the page would be to give your function a name and add a `setTimeout(functionName, 60000);` to the function. `60000` is the time between each update in miliseconds.